# How is XP/ Continuous Integration different from DevOps?

Tags: agile, extreme-programming, devops

Is DevOps just the new "cool" term for Extreme Programming?

Recently speaking with a company about doing some coaching work for them. They have decided that to be successful they need to do "DevOps" and want to know what my DevOps experience is. One of the people was even pretty insistent it wasn't "agile".

If you look at the Venn diagram of DevOps, on Wikipedia it's the center of Dev, QA and IT. If you look at the principles of XP, you are doing testing up front and you're doing continuous integration with regular releases to the customer.

Am I missing something? I'm just seeing a new term on concepts that are foundations of XP.

Answer (score 10):

XP and DevOps are different things. They don't contradict with each other, they can be used together, but they have different base concepts inside them.

- **XP**: many people wrongly thinks that XP is just a list of 12 practices. But in reality, XP is much more than these 12 practices. Extreme Programming is complex, consistent programming philosophy, with own values and principles, activities and roles. The main idea of XP: "*Hey, dude, you should do current tasks as soon as possible and don't think about tomorrow. If you will do something wrong today, we can easily fix it (if needed) tomorrow , because we have constant cost of change during whole of project*".
- **DevOps**: unlike XP, I have not many experience with DevOps. But in my understanding, the main idea of this methodology is: "*Programmers and admins should not to be enemies. Coding and deployment should not to be separated activities. Instead, these activities should be closely integrated with each other*"

So, some means by which the goals are achieved in these two methodologies can be the same (CI, Test Automation and so on), but their ideologies are different.

Comment: To take another angle on DevOps: In Agile we want cross-functional teams that are capable of delivering end-to-end on their value stream. DevOps takes this idea a step further either extending the act of development through deployment and operations, as the software delivers no value sitting in a GIT repo, or the other way where operations extends its role back into development to be involved in generating the value it provides instead of just deploying it. 

This is a pretty good article on DevOps as far as comprehensiveness and ease of understanding: http://theagileadmin.com/what-is-devops/

Comment: @Daniel your comment is almost exactly what I wanted to write as an answer. Why don't you turn your comment into an answer?